# AngularJs - model value does not reflect on ui in nested controllers case

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-model

I am using angularjs for one of the my module in application. I want to update UI of various locations on page, so that all ui components will work synchronously as the model value changes.

here is my html-

```
<fieldset ng-controller="controller1" >
        <legend>Divs with common controller</legend>
        <div style="background-color:#eee;padding:3px;">
            <input type="text" ng-model="Model1" />
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:#eee;padding:3px;">
            <input type="text" ng-model="Model1" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset ng-controller="controller1" >
        <legend>Divs with common controller</legend>
        <div style="background-color:#eee;padding:3px;" ng-controller="controller2">
            <input type="text" ng-model="Model1" />
            <input type="text" ng-model="Model2" />
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:#eee;padding:3px;">
            <input type="text" ng-model="Model1" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

and my javascript -

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp',[]);
        var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp',['testApp']);

        testApp.controller("controller1",['$scope',function($scope){
            $scope.Model1 = "testText";
        }]);

        testApp.controller("controller2",['$scope',function($scope){
            $scope.Model2 = "testText2";
        }]);
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['mainApp']);
```

In the html for first fieldset it is working properly. But in second fieldset it is not. So can anyone please tell me how do i achieve the functionality of first fieldset in second fieldset.
Thanks.

Comment: can explain about the question more shekhar

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/9463/ .if you can explain much about the problem !

Answer (score 1):

use `$rootScope` instead of `$scope`

Answer (score 0):

Can you use ng-controller="controller2" to particular input. 
Try this

`<div style="background-color:#eee;padding:3px;">
        <input type="text" ng-model="Model1" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="Model2" ng-controller="controller2" />
 </div>`

Comment: actually in my application it is not really the input element. Its a div in which another functionality is implemented. Here i have put input elements just for showing the scenario of my application

Comment: @Shekhar ok. Try to add controller2 to particular tag where Model2 is used

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you create 2 seperate scopes/instances for controller1

```
<div>
   // Root scope
   <div ng-controller="controller1">
      // Child scope A
      // scope = new controller1();
   </div>
   <div ng-controller="controller1">
      // Child scope B
      // scope = new controller1();
   </div>
</div>
```

You can solve this problem by using the `$rootScope` directly or by creating a service. The recommended way is to avoid `$rootScope` whenever possible and use a service instead.

Value is probably the easiest way to create a service. Note that you can also use `.service` or `.factory`. Read more in the documentation about services.

```
testApp.value('myValue', {
    data: 'testText'
});
```

*I'm using an object here so we can use this as a reference to the value, this is important for sharing data between controllers. If you want to know why then read more about reference & value types.*

Now inject this service into your controller and use this data instead:

```
testApp.controller("controller1",['$scope', 'myValue',function($scope, myValue){
    $scope.Model1 = myValue;
}]);
```

On the view we need to update the bindings to the reference of the service:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Model1.data" />
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5hd7ag6y/)

Answer (score -1):

USE THE DOT! ng-model without "." is bad. 
Please read this 
[What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482)
The issue is fully described there.